# Connect to MySQL database using python

Tags: python, mysql, database

So I am having a super hard time connecting to a local database using the python `mysql.connector` module. [image: MySQL Workbench screenshot]

So I am trying to connect using the highlighted connection. I use the password `abcdefghijkl` to log into the SQL environment. I am trying to connect to a database named `flight_school`.

My python script looks like so.

```py
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect("localhost", "root", "abcdefghijkl", "flight_school")

print(mydb.is_connected())
```

This above code in the arguments in the following order i.e.

- hostname = localhost,
- user = 'root',
- password = 'abcdefghijkl', and
- database name = 'flight_school'.

It's just not working. I get the following error.
[image: Image of the error]

I would really appreciate some advice, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read always the official [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connectargs.html)

Your connection string has to have this form(if you do it this way)

```
 mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
     host="localhost",
     user="root",
     passwd="testpaaword",
     database="testdb"
 )
```

Comment: I tried implementing the way you stated like so.


mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",
                               user="root",
                               passwd="abcdefghijkls",
                               database="flight_school")




But I keep on getting an error like so 
mysql.connector.errors.NotSupportedError: Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' is not supported

Comment: Any clue what that might mean

Comment: yes you have to enable in the mysql_native_password on your mysql server or for the user that logs in

Answer (score 1):

Please read always the official documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connectargs.html

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode, MySQLConnection

try:
    db_connection = MySQLConnection(user='root', password='', port='3306', database='your_database')
    print("Database connection made!")
except mysql.connector.Error as error:
    if error.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
        print("Database doesn't exist")
    elif error.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
        print("User name or password is wrong")
    else:
        print(error)
else:
    db_connection.close()

cursor = db_connection.cursor()

sql = ("commands")
cursor.execute(sql)
```

Answer (score -1):

Check out SQL-Alchemy module, works wonders from my experience.